# C# open file double click won't give args

Tags: c#

I am currently learning c# and stumbled on a problem, I can't seem to fix.
What I have done so far is, made a little gambling game where you roll a dice and so on. This is not too important I guess.
The user has the option to save his settings into a file.
What I want to do now is, when he double clicks the file to open up the game with the settings already loaded.

This is what I've got in my Program-class:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        if(args != null && args.Length > 0)
        {
            Application.Run(new Form1(args[0]));
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
```

And this in my Form1:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Form1(String SettingsFile)
        : this()
    {
        Settings = GameSettings.LoadFromFile(SettingsFile);
        MessageBox.Show(SettingsFile);
    }
```

If you need any further informations, please let me know.
And please be gentle on me. I already looked through google and still cant fix the issue.

Thanks guys

Comment: You need to pick an extension for the settings file & associate that extension with your application : http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-associate-file-type-or-protocol-program

Comment: looks like your program expects the settings file to be provided as a command line argument when the exe is started (you could do this if you ran it from the command prompt for instance).  If you already know the name (and location) of the settings file then you could just set this directly into the Form1 constructor.  e.g. Application.Run(new Form1(@"C:\settingsfile.txt")

Comment: Why not use the builtin functionality that comes with adding a App.config to your project? Seems like a lot of overhead to load settings the way you try and not really intuitive to start from the settings, not from the program.

Comment: In your Main Method, you are passing an array of strings (string[]) to the form, but your form's constructor receive a string. Try change that first